# Showing stability of a multi step method (numerical analysis)

Tags: numerical-methods

How would I show the stability of the following three step method

$y_{n+3}-y_{n}=h[\frac{3}{8}f(t_{n+3},y_{n+3})+\frac{9}{8}f(t_{n+2},y_{n+2})+\frac{9}{8}f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})+\frac{3}{8}f(t_n,y_n$)]

using the root method I am having trouble doing this

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? What have you tried so far?